# Let $ n \geq 2 $, $ f: \mathbb {R ^ n} \to\Bbb R $ continue and $ c \in \mathbb {R} $...

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ n \geq 2 $, $ f: \mathbb {R ^ n} \to \Bbb R $ continue and $ c \in \mathbb {R} $. If $ f ^ {- 1} (c) = \{x \in \mathbb {R ^ n}: f (x) = c\}$ is not empty and compact, show that there is $ R> 0 $ such that $ f (x) <c $ for all $ \| x \| > R $ or $ f (x)> c$ for all $ \| x \| > R $.

I am doing a demonstration by absurdity, but it is a bit difficult to reach a contradiction. I would like to know if you find another way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R>0$ be such that $f^{-1}(c)\subset B_R(0)$, where $B_R(0)$ is the ball of radius $R$ centered at $0$. This is possible by boundedness of the set $f^{-1}(c)$.

Fix $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|x\|>R$. There are two possibilities, either $f(x)>c$ or $f(x)<c$.

Case 1: $f(x)>c$. Let $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $\|y\|>R$. If $f(y)<c$, as the set $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_R(0)$ is connected, by the intermediate value theorem there has to be a $z$ in that set with $f(z)=c$, contrary to the choice of $R$.

Case 2: $f(x)<c$. This is similar.